# Finding at least one item in a VBA array in a range

Tags: vba, excel

I'm currently trying to find at least one item from my array in a range before proceeding, but the way I'm currently doing it checks that all values are in the range.

```
If Not accountRange.find(Array(11571, 11572, 11573, 11574, 11575)) Is Nothing Then
```

Ideally I'd have something like this:

```
If Not accountRange.find(Array(11571, xlOr, 11572, xlOr, 11573, xlOr, 11574, xlOr, 11575))
```

The only workaround I can see is checking each condition individually, like so:

```
If Not accountRange.find(11571) Is Nothing Or _ 
    Not accountRange.Find(11572) Is Nothing Or _
    Not accountRange.Find(11573) Is Nothing Or _
    Not accountRange.Find(11574) Is Nothing Or _
    Not accountRange.Find(11575) Is Nothing Then
```

but obviously this will get tedious when I have more things to check in the range.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could write a function like this:

```
Function ValInRange(vals As Variant, R As Range) As Boolean
    Dim item As Variant
    For Each item In vals
        If Not R.Find(item) Is Nothing Then
            ValInRange = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next item
End Function
```

Then `ValInRange(Array(11571, 11572, 11573, 11574, 11575), accountRange)` will return `True` if one of the passed numbers is in the range. Otherwise, it returns the default Boolean value of `False`.

Comment: Thanks for this, it works perfectly! Seems a little unfortunate there's not a way to do this using the `.Find` method though

Comment: @RiverBanana Things are seldom easy in VBA. It is an old language which hasn't changed much from the mid 90s.